# foreach and while errors in cart system

Tags: php, loops, paypal

I'm programming a cart system with paypal I am having troubles with the foreach who sets different products into paypal form this is the code:

```
public function GetUserCart(){  //we get the items in the user cart
 $mysqli = $this->connection();
 $data = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM carrito WHERE usuario_id='$this->username_id'");
 return $data;
    }
//we get the values of the products
public function GetPictureData($id_product,$picture_column){
$mysqli = $this->connection();
$validacion = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pinturas WHERE id='$id_product' LIMIT 1");
$data = $validacion->fetch_assoc();
return $data[$picture_column];
    }


$itemstopaypalname=''; //name of the product
 $itemstopaypalprice=''; //price of the product
 //we get the items in the user cart
 $querys = $this->GetUserCart();
 $dataset = array(); //this is for use outside a while
 while ($data = $querys->fetch_array()) {   
 $dataset[] = $data;
 }
 $cart .= '<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="'.$this->url.'files/libs/paypal.php">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="'.$this->email().'">';
 $num = 1;
 foreach($dataset as $k => $v){  //this is where im having troubles
 $itemstopaypalname.=$this->GetPictureData($v['producto_id'],"titulo"); 
 $itemstopaypalprice.=$this->GetPictureData($v['producto_id'],"price"); 
 $cart .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_'.$num.'" value="'. $itemstopaypalname.'">';
 $cart .= '<input type="hidden" name="amount_'.$num.'" value="'. $itemstopaypalprice.'">';
 $num = $num + 1; 
 }
```

so when comes the second and third product repeats the first and second respectively:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="mono">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="567">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="monocosos">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="5674678">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="monocososImage Upload">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="56746782450">
```

so you can see 567 repeats in every amount, how i can solve this?

Comment: `$itemstopaypalname.=` this will concatenate previous strings also.Try 

`$itemstopaypalname=$this->GetPictureData($v['producto_id'],"titulo"); $itemstopaypalprice=$this->GetPictureData($v['producto_id'],"price");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$itemstopaypalname.=` this will concatenate previous strings also.

Try

`$itemstopaypalname=$this->GetPictureData($v['producto_id'],"titulo"); $itemstopaypalprice=$this->GetPictureData($v['producto_id'],"price");`